# Jenkins & email-ext questions

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've been looking into using the email-ext plugin for our Jenkins/DotCi setup, however i can't seem to find any resource on which where we should be storing our templates for the email?

I can modify the templates listed "/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates" to contain the information i want to have sent.

Does the email template live in the root similar to the .ci.yml file?

Comment: My issue has been resolved. To configure the email-ext plugin within a Jenkins/DotCi setup, user needs to go to the Config menu under Manage Jenkins as the selected answer states.

If you do not see that, you probably lack admin access!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find "Extended E-mail Notification" under the "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System"
There you can find all the configuration settings for this plugin - including "Default Content"

Answer (score 1):

The templates go into JENKINS_HOME\email-templates

To check that it is configured right, go to a project that you have run at least once and click on 'Email Template Testing' in the sidebar.  Type in the full name of your template file.

If the file can't be found you will get an error in red beneath the input box.  Otherwise you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Question: We run using DotCi plugin on Jenkins. When a build fails, will Jenkins automatically call the template to send the mail? or would i have to specifically call the plugin email-ext?